# Creating a workflow in a single form in Struts2

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I'm using [`struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0`](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/detail?name=struts2-jquery-plugin-3.7.0.jar&can=2&q=). I'm looking for a component that can create a workflow by exhibiting (creating) multiple steps in a single form on a page in which the current step is processed partially and display the next step if and only if the current step passes validations.

All the steps must be performed sequentially in a defined order.

For example, in a user registration form, personnel information of a user must be filled up first before filling up her contact information and so on.

If any validation is violated while filling up personnel information then, the next step (to fill up contact information) must not be executed. It should only be executed, if no validation is violated in personnel information.

Currently, I can only see [`<sj:tabbedpanel>`](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TabbedPanelTag) which doesn't seem to fulfill these requirements.

Is there any component that can be used in Struts2  to fulfill these requirements?

<sub>**Long story short :** I'm looking for exactly the same component as provided by PrimeFaces [`<p:wizard>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf) Anyway, I need to create a workflow in which a single page of activities can be exhibited in different and sequential steps. Is there a handy way that can make it possible?</sub>

Comment: Try jquery tabbed pannel .. and use Ajax calls

Comment: [`<sj:tabbedpanel>`](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TabbedPanelTag) as I linked in the question is not appropriate to meet the requirements specified in the question.

Comment: Okay May be try this JSF plugin JSFPLUGIN [http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/jsf-plugin.html]  You may find Your prinefaces functionality ..

Comment: AFAIK there is none out of the box. But take a look at this plugin: https://github.com/aleksandr-m/struts2-actionflow. And for the single page requirement you can send ajax requests instead of submitting forms.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a plugin-in or component for **multi-step form** in struts2. Well there is no such implementations now, but you can create one of your own. There are many so examples in google.

This one implementation I found in [struts2](http://www.java-only.com/LoadTutorial.javaonly?id=42).

Even this is not a bad option. You need to program the underlying logic :) 
[CSS3-Jquery](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/)